# Addtoany: Keep share buttons from appearing in widgets

Tags: wordpress, plugins, sharing

I am using wordpress with the theme Twenty Fourteen. I installed the plugin AddToAny for social sharing buttons. Everything works well, but I have one question: How can I keep share buttons from appearing in widgets? I tried already to change all the possible settings, but the buttons don't disappear. Can anyone help me? 
Thank you a lot. 
Best wishes,
pradhana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to just hide them using css.  Something like this might work in your css:

```
.widget .a2a_kit {
   display: none;
}
```

The .widget will only select instances of addToAny that appear inside widgets.